# BIgQuery UDF Javascript works in Web UI but not embedded

Tags: javascript, configuration, request, google-bigquery, udf

I managed to get a query working with the Web UI and UDF.  When I ported it my embedded code I get a 400 reply, "missing required parameter".  I have my javascript code in google cloud storage bucket and I tested it with the Web UI option to use the external code rather than code in UDF editor box.  You have to clear that text box and select the link with this line in the options area:

```
UDF Source URIs Edit Inline UDF
```

So it means BQ Web UI is finding my UDF and it works the same as with the same code in the UDF editor.  My guess is that the request is not formatted properly.

I am following the documentation to modify the query... The documentation is [here][1] and clearly just a fragment of the complete request API.

```
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "userDefinedFunctionResources": [
        {
          "inlineCode": "var someCode = 'here';"
        },
        {
          "resourceUri": "gs://some-bucket/js/lib.js"
        }
      ],
      "query": "select a from myFunc(T);"
    }
  }
```

I interpreted it this way:

```
    var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
      'projectId': project_id,
      'timeoutMs': '60000',
      'configuration': {
          'query' : {
              'userDefinedFunctionResources': [
               {
                  'inlineCode' : ''
               },
               {
                  'resourceUri': 'gs://cloudfiledatetype/UDF/udfLatestProcTimeAllRegions.js'
               }
              ],
              'query': queryAll
          }
      }
    });
```

By the way, I tried to remove the inLineCode option and got the same error.
There is no documentation on how to format the FULL request ...

As a test, I removed the reference to the UDF and removed the configuration option so the request is the bread and butter:

```
    var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
      'projectId': project_id,
      'timeoutMs': '60000',
      'query': queryAll
    });
```

And this works fine: no 400 error.

My guess is that I have an error in my request but I cannot find a more detailed example in the Google site or here in SO.

I also read that there is concern about UDF living on an being depricated.  I am using UDF because I am not able to the desired query without it.  I could probably do it with LAG, but query always gets rejected on a format option on the OVER definition...Arggg..

Full working REAL-LIFE examples of advanced features would really be appreciated Google.

For better documentation: here is my UDF:

```
  var lastInputA = -1;
  function passthroughExample(row, emit) {

    // handle 
    if (row.inputA != lastInputA) {
      emit({outputC: row.inputC});
    }
    lastInputA = row.inputA;
  }


  bigquery.defineFunction(
    'passthrough',                           // Name of the function exported to SQL
    ['inputA', 'inputB', 'inputC'],          // Names of input columns
    [{'name': 'outputC', 'type': 'integer'}],
    passthroughExample                       // Reference to JavaScript UDF
  );
```

It does something pretty simple, but I have seen a couple posts on SO on how to handle a similar problem.
I have multiple entier with the same process window, for each day a startTime and endTime, but processed on different days with a different process time.  I want to pick the later one as it has the latest code.  Notice the code only outputs the latest process times.  This way, in the query I can do this

```
    WHERE
      processTime IN ( (
      SELECT
        outputC
      FROM
        passthrough (
        SELECT
          summaryStartTimeStamp AS inputA,
          summaryEndTimeStamp AS inputB,
          processTime AS inputC
```

If you do a query to get all the days, and order with ascending start time, and descending process time, you get rows with the latest process time and then rows with repeated startTime and endTime and earlier process time.. So the UDF finds when the startTime changes and emits this row.  It rejects the rows until startTime changes again.

Here is a sample of the data before the UDF.  This is the input to the UDF.

```
summaryStartTimeStamp   summaryEndTimeStamp processTime
1468206000000   1468292400000   1478668368824
1468206000000   1468292400000   1474504378494
1468206000000   1468292400000   1472261683703
1468206000000   1468292400000   1471908635453
1468292400000   1468378800000   1478668668857
1468292400000   1468378800000   1474504654098
1468292400000   1468378800000   1472261923772
1468292400000   1468378800000   1471908956622
1468378800000   1468465200000   1478669028973
1468378800000   1468465200000   1474504910553
1468378800000   1468465200000   1472262223831
1468378800000   1468465200000   1471916440493
1468465200000   1468551600000   1478669269089
1468465200000   1468551600000   1474505174929
1468465200000   1468551600000   1472262463965
1468465200000   1468551600000   1471917212326
```

Here is the output of the UDF with redudant lines removed and the latest process time in outputC

```
outputA         outputB          outputC
1468206000000   1468292400000   1478668368824
1468292400000   1468378800000   1478668668857
1468378800000   1468465200000   1478669028973
1468465200000   1468551600000   1478669269089
```

Here is the query using the UDF in the webUI...

```
SELECT
  outputA, outputB, outputC
FROM
   passthrough (
  SELECT summaryStartTimeStamp as inputA, summaryEndTimeStamp as inputB, processTime as inputC
  FROM
    [xxx removed ]
  WHERE
    eventType == "MAPFIT" 
  GROUP BY 
    inputA, inputB, inputC
  ORDER BY
     inputA,inputC DESC
  LIMIT
    1000 )
ORDER by outputA
LIMIT 1000
```

with this UDF in the UDF editor window

```
var lastInputA = -1;
function passthroughExample(row, emit) {

    // handle 
    if (row.inputA != lastInputA) {
       emit({outputC: row.inputC});
    }
    lastInputA = row.inputA;
}


bigquery.defineFunction(
    'passthrough',                           
    ['inputA', 'inputB', 'inputC'],         
    [{'name': 'outputC', 'type': 'integer'}],
    passthroughExample                     
);
```

In this example, I output the start and end times for readability.  In the inline code I used a modified version that only outputs the process time so select the process Times that are in the sub query.

I could possibly do this without UDF by having the same query and then detecting with the startTime does not equal the startTime lagging by one.

My question is: why the missing required parameter for the javascript formatted request at the top of this question.. Thanks

UPDATE:
I have been trying all possible combinations of the request definition and I have a different error now.. I got rid of the"400: required parameter missing"  error.  Now I get "400, Unknown TVF: passthrough".  "passthrough" is the name of the UDF.

So it seems the request JSON parser is satified with the configuration, but it is still not able to find the UDF.  Here is the new request definition:

```
requests = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
      'projectId': project_id,
      'timeoutMs': '60000',
      "userDefinedFunctionResources": [
           {
               "resourceUri": "gs://cloudfiledatetype/UDF/udfLatestProcTimeAllRegions.js" 
           },
       ],
       'query': queryAll

});
```

Note that if I issue the query in the WebUI and point to this UDF, it runs fine. THus, I think the issue is just with embedded jobs.

I also tried adding the same function in the other way:  Now I used this request where the UDF is added as javascript blob in the "inLineCode" option.

```
requests = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
      'projectId': project_id,
      'timeoutMs': '60000',
      "userDefinedFunctionResources": [
            {
            "inlineCode": "var lastInputA = -1; function passthroughExample(row, emit) { if (row.inputA != lastInputA) {  emit({outputC: row.inputC});  }  lastInputA = row.inputA;}  bigquery.defineFunction(  'passthrough', ['inputA', 'inputB', 'inputC'], [{'name': 'outputC', 'type': 'integer'}], passthroughExample);"
           }
       ],
       'query': queryAll

});
```

Once again I get a 400 response with "Unknown TVF: passthrough".
So I have no idea why this is failing...Is it my request definition or is it that UDF does not work outside of the WebUI???  Thanks.

P.S. If someone can add the tabs Big Query and UserDefinedFunctions to the tabs of this question it would be really appreciated.  Otherwise the guys at Google might not see this....

Comment: Anyone with enough points please able to change the tag on this to include big Query and UserdefinedFunctions so that the guys at Google can see it.  I think its a pretty basic problem with the feature...its works fine in the WebUI but not in normal job call...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use [`Jobs: query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) API which does not support UDF
So, you need to use [`Jobs: insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) API with [`configuration.query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query) property which does support [`userDefinedFunctionResources`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.userDefinedFunctionResources)

So, to summarize - instead of [`query`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.9.2/bigquery?method=query) method try [`startQuery`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.9.2/bigquery?method=startQuery) method

Comment: that is a helpful response.  Any chance you could provide the syntax please?